# Is there a way to stress test a website with Apache log requests with Python script?

Tags: python, apache, stress-testing

Have been fiddling with a Python script that would take POST, GET requests from apache log and stress test a website upon the requests found from apache log for quite some time by now.

Pretty much I could get the requests from the log file and parse them and convert them to CSV file with some help from here - https://lincolnloop.com/blog/load-testing-jmeter-part-3-replaying-apache-logs/

But now I am stuck - I haven't quite found a good stress tester that would take such requests in and stress test upon them. Jmeter doesn't cut it because still the GUI would needed to be used and that's no good as the purpose is to have simple and portable Python script. Of course any modules would be OK.

If anybody has any good ideas or a bit of code to share then would be immensely grateful!

Thanks and have a beautiful day! :)

Johannes

Answer (score 1):

Is Python a must for your use case? If not, you could try [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) free and open-source Java-based load and performance testing solution.

It provides [Access Log Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for. See [How to use Access Log Sampler to Generate Traffic with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65141-how-to-use-access-log-sampler-to-generate-traffic) for detailed walkthrough.

Alternative option is using [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) and [Apache Log Playback script](http://sourceforge.net/p/grinder/mailman/message/23424735/). In this case you'll be able to integrate it with your existing Python code but Java will still be required.

Answer (score 0):

The `Locust` python framework allows load and stress testing.

An example from their website:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class WebsiteTasks(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post("/login", {
            "username": "test_user",
            "password": ""
        })

    @task
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task
    def about(self):
        self.client.get("/about/")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = WebsiteTasks
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 15000
```

Read more here: http://locust.io/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But as I understand the locust generates the requests himself - "The idea is that during a test, a swarm of locusts will attack your website. The behavior of each locust (or test user if you will) is defined by you" Am I wrong?

Comment: Locust has a very convenient mode of operation wherein it can use a pool of worker nodes. Locust can also easily read in your access logs in whatever format you desire. For example, if you want to test things like Range requests, its useful to write your access logs in JSON and capture the Range request header; and to ensure that your timestamps have something better than second-level granularity. Locust is a Python library, so much easier to do. If you want to replay POST data, you may want to log using the forensic logging.